# AuthSub with PHP

Tags: php, google-api, authsub

Can I use AuthSub with PHP ? I want to use Google  API with PHP but don't want to install Zend Framework.I'm goolging and not found with AuthSub class for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google supports both AuthSub and OAuth standard. The OAuth standard is newer. PHP has support for the OAuth standard, details of which can be found in http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found :( need to install but I don't have permission to install that. I'm using share hosting.

Comment: I try to install in MAMP. $ sudo pecl install /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php oauth-0.99.9 but make: *** [oauth.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ is a php library for OAuth. You can use it since you are on a shared host.

Comment: I can't find example for that. I want example look like http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.examples.fireeagle.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use just the GData portion of Zend:
[link text](http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata)

I've used it successfully to connect to Google accounts, and Google Apps accounts.

Comment: it's need to install Zend Framework ,right ? I don't want to install Zend Framework.

Comment: now, Gdata is working but Gdata don't have domain share content for Zend :( I want to use domain share content. Need to do with oAuth or Authsub with Zend.

Comment: Nope, you don't need the whole Zend Framework, you can just get the GData stuff (at the link in the answer).  I'm not sure what you mean by "domain share content" though.